# remove blue glow from a submit button

Tags: html, css, forms, internet-explorer, button

I already tried several solutions found online on this website and many others but nothing solved the problem. I tried
`Outline:0;`, `Outline:none;`, `box-shadow:none;`, tried specifying a class etc. etc.

I created my own stylish button and the blue glow being put around it looks very ugly.

It's also important I can remove it, as I'm creating a multi-page form (survey) with 3 buttons below each page, I don't want one of them to have a blue outline. They should all look the same.

I can't provide a links since I work offline.

This is my code:

```
    a.button,
    input[type='reset'],
    input[type='button'],
    input[type='submit'],
    input[type='submit']:focus
     {
        -moz-border-radius: 2px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
        background-color: #f9f9f9; /* Alabaster */
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,                 from(#f9f9f9), to(#f1f1f1));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #f1f1f1);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #f1f1f1);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #f1f1f1);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #f1f1f1);
        background-image: linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #f1f1f1);
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(226, 226, 226, 0.8);
        border-radius: 5px; 
        -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        -o-border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        color: #000000;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 100px;
        width: 120px;
        filter:         progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#f9f9f9,         endColorstr=#f1f1f1);
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 700;
        line-height: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 4px 0px;
        text-decoration: none;
        vertical-align: middle;
        white-space: nowrap;
        outline:transparent;
    }

    <span style="float:left;">
                                <span style="direction:rtl;float:left;margin-right:10px;">
                                    <input type="submit" name="_NNext" class="mrNext" style="width: 70px;" value="Volgende" alt="Volgende"></input>
                                    <input type="submit" name="_NPrev" class="mrPrev" style="width: 70px;" value="Vorige" alt="Vorige"></input>
                                </span>
                                <input type="submit" name="_NStop" class="mrStop" style="width: 70px;" value="Stop" alt="Stop"></input>
                            </span>
```

[image]

Comment: add outline:0 / none !important; in your code?

Comment: What internet explorer version are you using? Because your code works fine in IE 10. http://fiddle.jshell.net/3aurrLyr/1/

Comment: I tried using !important as well. I'm using internet explorer 11

Comment: It works fine for me too.. try to check is there any conflict in your css files?

Comment: i visited fiddle.jshell.net/3aurrLyr/1 
but the buttons are static here, no hover-effect and not able to click them. problem occurs when a button has been clicked. (on the next page) it gets a blue glow around it

Comment: i used error check, found 1 mistake and fixed it, but it didn't change anything